# Find a string inside a bytebuffer

Tags: java, string, bytebuffer

I'm switching from C to Java. I'm wondering about how to find a string inside a bytebuffer, is there something like memchr in java? The bytebuffer is only partly a string, the rest is raw bytes so any java method has to work on bytes + chars.

I am also searching for something like strsep in java to split strings.

Comment: java.lang.String - methods split() or substring can be used to split the string. You should in general read the javadocs of this class.

Comment: You can split string with `String.split()`

Comment: @Blub - What is the size/length of bytebuffer?

Comment: Not a good question - because it has two questions in one. Please split up the two (using split? :-))

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the ByteBuffer into a String and use indexOf which likely to work.

```
ByteBuffer bb = /* non-direct byte buffer */
String text = new String(bb.array(), 0, bb.position(), bb.remaing());
int index = text.indexOf(searchText);
```

This has a non-trivial overhead as it creates a String.  The alternative is a brute force String search which will be faster but takes time to write.

Comment: This String constructor is deprecated, because it doesn't take the character encoding into account. Suggested: `String text = new String(bb.array(), 0, bb.position(), charset);` where `charset` is the encoding to use, or the default one `Charset.defaultCharset()`

Comment: If you are reading raw C string it is most likely ISO-8859-1 encoded in which case this method is fine. Being explicit doesn't hurt performance much so it being clear is perhaps better.

Comment: Downside to this approach, and similar, is that you have to read the whole string - not a streaming solution.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to encode the character string into bytes using the correct character encoding for your application. Then use a string search algorithm like Rabin-Karp or Boyer-Moore to find the resulting byte sequence within the buffer. Or, if your buffers are small, you could just perform a brute force search.

I'm not aware of any open source implementations of these search algorithms, and they aren't part of core Java.

Answer (score 1):

From [Fastest way to find a string in a text file with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460684/fastest-way-to-find-a-string-in-a-text-file-with-java/28792225#28792225):

The best realization I've found in MIMEParser: https://github.com/samskivert/ikvm-openjdk/blob/master/build/linux-amd64/impsrc/com/sun/xml/internal/org/jvnet/mimepull/MIMEParser.java

```
/**
  * Finds the boundary in the given buffer using Boyer-Moore algo.
  * Copied from java.util.regex.Pattern.java
  *
  * @param mybuf boundary to be searched in this mybuf
  * @param off start index in mybuf
  * @param len number of bytes in mybuf
  *
  * @return -1 if there is no match or index where the match starts
  */

  private int match(byte[] mybuf, int off, int len) {
```

Needed also:

```
  private void compileBoundaryPattern();
```

Answer (score 0):

The String class has a nice split method [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), which can split the string into an iterable collection of tokens according to given delimiter(s). The tokens collection can contain the delimiter if needed. Example:

```
String s = "abc:def-ghi|jkl";
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, ":-|");
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
  System.out.print(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

Expected result:

> abcdefghijkl